# Reuse a tableview cell with CALayer

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview cell with a reuse-identifier set in storyboard.
After checking some conditions I want to draw different things on the contentView of the cell.
My problem is when the tableview re-uses the cell, the CAShapeLayer from another cell persists, so it's showing the new drawing over the (re-used) drawing.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"StatusCell"];

    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([[object valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"sending"]) {
        CAShapeLayer *progressLayer;
        //...Configure and draw Layer with UIBezierPath
        [cell.contentView.layer addSublayer:progressLayer];
    } else if ([[object valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"sent"]) {
        CAShapeLayer *sentLayer;
        //...Configure and draw Layer with UIBezierPath
        [cell.contentView.layer addSublayer:sentLayer];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

So I tried to give the CAShapeLayer a name and delete the layer from the re-used cell before creating a new CAShapeLayer.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"StatusCell"];

    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    for (CALayer *layer in cell.contentView.layer.sublayers) {
        if ([layer.name isEqualToString:@"sending"] || [layer.name isEqualToString:@"sent"]) {
            [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
        }
    }

    if ([[object valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"sending"]) {
        CAShapeLayer *progressLayer;
        progressLayer.name = @"sending";
        //...Configure and draw Layer with UIBezierPath
        [cell.contentView.layer addSublayer:progressLayer];
    } else if ([[object valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"sent"]) {
        CAShapeLayer *sentLayer;
        sentLayer.name = @"sent";
        //...Configure and draw Layer with UIBezierPath
        [cell.contentView.layer addSublayer:sentLayer];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

But with this method I get an exception when scrolling the tableview `CALayerArray was mutated while being enumerated`

Can someone point me in the right direction how to do it the correct way?

Comment: I think you should make custom views for each cell state to avoid redrawing continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to subclass `UITableViewCell`, assign these layers as properties, and manage their visibility using `hidden` property of `CALayer`.

Create a custom cell class

```
@interface StatusCell: UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer *progressLayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer *sentLayer;

@end
```

Assign `StatusCell` class name to your cell prototype in storyboard.

Create the layers – as you could notice, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is not the best place to do it, as it is called often during cell life cycle. I usually create properties in `init` methods, as your cell is storyboard-based, you can also use the `awakeFromNib` method, it is also called only once during nib-based cells' life cycle.

```
@implementation StatusCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    CAShapeLayer *progressLayer;
    // configuraion
    progressLayer.hidden = YES;
    self.progressLayer = progressLayer;

    // repeat for sentLayer.
}

@end
```

In your cellForRow method you set one layer to be hidden, and other to be visible. You can adjust layers' positions, if required.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    StatusCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"StatusCell"];

    // Optionally adjust your layers' frames if your cell has dynamic height. 

    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.progressLayer.hidden = ![[object valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"sending"];
    cell.sentLayer.hidden = ![[object valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"sent"];

    return cell;
}
```